# no such option: --extra-index-url http://localhost:8080 / CondaValueError: pip returned an error

Tags: pip, conda, python-3.8

This is the environment.yml file:

```
name: project
channels:
    - conda-forge
    - defaults
dependencies:
  - black=19.10b0
  - numpy=1.19.1
  - pandas=1.1.2
  - pip=20.1.1
  - python=3.8
  - pip:
      - --extra-index-url http://localhost:8080
```

Based on it I intend to establish a virtual environment by:

```
conda env create -f environment.yml
```

But this yield the following obscure error message:

```
no such option: --extra-index-url http://localhost:8080

CondaValueError: pip returned an error.
```

I don't know what to make of it as pip with version >= 20 definitely has such an option:

```
john@dsb:~/workspace/project/python/project$ pip help install
[...]
Package Index Options:
[...]
  --extra-index-url <url>     Extra URLs of package indexes to use in addition to --index-url. Should follow the same rules as --index-url.
[...]
```

Any ideas?

---

- Python 3.8.6
- pip 20.1.1
- conda 4.3.30

Comment: Works for me (Conda v4.9.2). Also, this same option is demonstrated in the Advanced Pip Example on the repo, so the fact [that example was added in Conda v4.4](https://github.com/conda/conda/commit/0ce1f87168fd970e95002170170aa619b272357a), indicates it's likely your Conda version.

Comment: The problem is that you are passing the `--extra-index-url` to `pip` instead of to `pip install`. Compare `pip install --extra-index-url http://localhost:8080 pip` to `pip --extra-index-url http://localhost:8080 install pip`.